# Node.js youtube video intercept to work around youtube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, youtube

I'm new to Node.js, Socket.IO and Express.js, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about solving the following problem:

I have developed a simple site (with the above mentioned tools) that embeds some YouTube videos, and allows users to watch them on the site (fairly simple right?). The problem is if these videos get taken down by the uploader on YouTube, or are not available in your country, there is nothing coming back in the JSON metadata from the YouTube API to let the developer know this. YouTube just shows a video with white noise and:

> Error: this video is not available in your country

To avoid this, I'm thinking of intercepting some of the streaming video and making sure it has content. Can somebody suggest a better way? Or give me ideas on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Could you link to an example video that's been taken down by the uploader.